# Help with ceiling fan wiring. Red black and white wires

Tags: electrical

Over the weekend I started a project to install a ceiling fan and hook it up to 2 switches, 1 to control the light and 1 to control the fan. There was originally one switch controlling a light fixture. I ran a new line 12-3 from the ceiling to the electrical box. The power coming in to the box has a wire that is black, red and white. I cannot figure out how I am supposed to wire this to the switches so I can accomplish this project. Any ideas or diagrams would be great. Thank you so much. I have included 2 photos. One is of the original wiring that was at the switch and another with the power and the new 12-3 wire that I ran. Thank you so much for your help.[image: Original wiring][image]

Comment: The original wiring looks like it has two 12/3 cables in the box (one in and one out to the fan), so what did you do different?  Why did you "add" a 12/3 when it looks like one was there already?

Comment: There was no ground wire on the wires coming into the box or going to the light fixture. Is that still a 12/3 wire?

Comment: Yes, no ground would still be 12/3, but very old.  Today the only thing you can really by is technically "12/3 with ground" but no one says "with ground" because it's just assumed.  Do the black and red wire both have voltage on them (120v with respect to the white wire)?

Comment: Yes they do have voltage. How would I go about wiring it with 2 switches? Every diagram that I have found has a ground in the diagram.

Comment: Does the power supply cable have a ground?

Comment: Can you post photos looking squarely into the backs of the boxes involved?

Comment: Just for fun, make sure there's not 240v between the red and black.  Might as well check for odd stuff while we are at it.  And yea, all modern wiring has ground.  Does your house have mostly 2-prong outlets (no ground)?  Can you pull out an outlet or two and see if it's actually grounded?

Comment: This is a mystery because you have two boxes each with **two** /3 cables in them, and it's unclear how they relate. Is the first box connected to the second?  What was in the hole-in-the-wall before it became a hole?  Which one is the location you ultimately want the switch?  Why is your power cable /3?  You need to [edit] to backfill some of this info and make the question more clear.